# React.js transitions not working for "fade out"

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a React.js component that I am trying to "fade out" using the React CSS Transitions.  It is working fine for the fade in, but when I click to remove the object, it just disappears immediately (instead of the nice fading effect).

Code:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
    transitionName="example"
    transitionAppear={true}
    transitionLeave={true}
    transitionEnterTimeout={600}
    transitionAppearTimeout={600}
    transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
>
    some object
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

CSS:

/*React transitions*/

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}

.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This works fine? Are you sure there are no other errors?

Comment: No errors.  The fade in works just fine.  But when it "disappears" there's no fade out effect.

Comment: I can't see any issues when trying to reproduce. See [here](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/zqvRZg?editors=0110)

Comment: I could not see any problem in my side. I check your codepen link and it works fine for me. 
here is some points my be useful for you:
1. `transitionLeaveTimeout={300}` may fire very fast.
2. there was some conflict with other JavaScript statements or library
3. try to check with other browser or device to verify problem exist

Answer (score 6):

[Here is a working jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilkumar80/69z2wepo/34420/)

```
var {CSSTransitionGroup} = React.addons;

var Fade = React.createClass({
    getInitialState () {
        return {
            items: ["Hello"]
        }
    },
    clickHandler (e) {
        this.setState({items:[]});
    },
    render: function() {
        var {items} = this.state;
        return (
            <CSSTransitionGroup  transitionName="example"
        transitionAppear={true}
        transitionLeave={true}
        transitionEnterTimeout={600}
        transitionAppearTimeout={600}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
            {items.map(item => <div onClick={this.clickHandler}>{item}</div>)}
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Fade/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I guess you were trying to remove the child node using DOM manipulation. This transition will work only if you allow it to re-render through react render method.

Answer (score -1):

I Found the problem in your CSS just remove commented line:

```
.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  /*transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;*/
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that line could cause the object to disappear immediately. And I think the transition duration is supposed to be different for the different transitions.

Comment: @ArneHugo the code is [hear](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/zqvRZg?editors=0110) and I modified code and see the result. when I comment mentioned line showing and hiding are absolutely same.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, as the line you removed changes transition-duration to be 300ms when leaving active state. However, that seems to be by design. Also, with a 300ms transition duration, the element should not seem to "disappear immediately", but fade over 300ms (which is plenty long enough to see it fade). The asker probably has some other bug in his code that causes his problem.

Comment: thanks @ArneHugo I totally agree with you. base on my experience  in some hardware spec certain animation may run fast or ignored ;) but there is no problem in code.

Comment: Wrong answer. Please delete it. Wrong and does not make sense.